# ath error - Could not stop RX, DMS failed to stop

Tags: 11.04, atheros, asus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

I've just installed Ubuntu 11.04 on an Asus EeeBox PC (EB1012P) using Unetbootin to create a bootable live USB. I didn't notice any errors or failures in the installation process. I'm working in the terminal screen at <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> (although <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> still brings up the desktop GUI) and every two minutes or so, this message interrupts whatever I do:

```
[60256.139549] ath: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms [AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020]
[60256.154150] ath: Could not stop RX, we could be confusing the DMA engine when we start RX up
[60256.180130] ath: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms [AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020]
```

I really don't even know how to begin troubleshooting this, or if it's even a serious problem. It doesn't really interrupt any processes I start, it just prints that text out onto my screen in the middle of whatever I'm typing. I don't know if it still does this in other <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>Fx</kbd> terminals, or in a terminal opened in the GUI screen. I'm going to start by googling the addresses in square brackets and see what they get me.

Any suggestions or interpretations of these errors are much appreciated!

Khiya

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

It's a known problem with the wireless drivers, not ubuntu specific.
(e.g.: search for openwrt, you'll find they have problems also)

Worst thing that happens is that the wireless connection drops out.
Annoying but for most users nothing to serious.

Updating to a newer ubuntu version (e.g. 11.10) should help. Although
not all problems are solved yet.

Comment: Upgrading to a newer version is not really a suggestion.